# IPython Notebook crashes Macbook Pro every day around noon

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

This is an odd problem I am having to which I have no solution!

Every day, at around noon -- sometimes closer to 1pm -- my computer locks up. It only does so if I am running an IPython Notebook kernel.

I am running Mavericks on a MBPr 2013.

Has anyone else had this issue or related?

How can I investigate further?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just a guess, but maybe there is a feature turned on in IPython that's calling home for updates or something, and it's running at that time?  maybe check to see if it has that feature, and turn it off, and see if that helps?

EDITED: see my comment below, I don't think this is an ipython related issue.

Comment: I wouldn't know where to start to look. Any ideas?

Comment: After doing a few minutes of looking, I am going to retract my answer, I don't believe that this is the issue.  You might have something running in the background at that time, but I don't think it's ipython related.  You can still check to see if something kicks off around that time on your Mac by running "top" or something at around that time of day and just watching what's going on.

Comment: Thanks. What is 'top'?